# Firefox extension to alert on missing .js files?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, mozilla

I am porting a Web App to a new environment. Due to changed paths, some references to JavaScript Files () are broken. I know of no way to make Firefox / Firebug / the web developer toolbar to warn on missing JS files, or at least issue an information somewhere.

Am I overlooking something?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Net tab of Firebug should highlight any missing JS files in red.

Comment: I am blind. There they are. Thank you.